# Sensitivity of starting point for Newton's method

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson

I have been trying to solve the following minimization problem using Newton's method:

$\min _{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}} f(\boldsymbol{x})=x_{1}^{4}-2 x_{2} x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{1}^{2}-2 x_{1}+5$

Using the starting point $\boldsymbol{x_0}=[1,4]^T$
the method converges in one iteration as
[contour plot with iterates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mi0g.png)

If I use this starting point $\boldsymbol{x_0}=[-3,2]^T$

the method converges in 6 iterations as

[contour plot with iterates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah1dY.jpg)

What is the difference of these starting points. Why does the method converge in one iteration for the first starting point, but not for the second?

Comment: If the starting point is in between attractive basins, it will be sensitive to initial condition.  This relates to Newton's fractal.